# Counter in section title, table of contents increases it

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, counters

I'm trying to add a counter to subsection titles.
For example:

1. Design tests

   1.1 Test 1. A test

   1.2 Test 2. Another test
2. Functional tests

   2.1 Test 3. Yet another test

The problem is, since the counter is also increased in the table of contents, table of contents will show:

1.1 Test 1. A test (and the other two tests will be 2 and 3)

but then the section in the document will be:

1.1 Test 4. A test (and the other two tests will be 5 and 6)

How could I skip the table of contents from using the counter?

Here is a sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{test}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\newtest}[1]{
\refstepcounter{test} \label{test:#1} 
Test \thetest #1
}

\begin{document}
   \title{Test example}

   \maketitle

   \clearpage

   \tableofcontents

   \clearpage

    \section{Design tests}
      \subsection{\newtest{A test}}
      \subsection{\newtest{Another test}}
    \section{Functional tests}
      \subsection{\newtest{Yet another test}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In my point this is a bad idea! What is the purpose of the counter at all?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks. The purpose is to count the tests that will appear in several sections of the document. Also, every test is intended to have several subsections (like test description, procedure, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach prevents the `\refstepcounter` code if it's not executed in the `\tableofcontents`, by using a conditional named `\ifnotintoc`, being set to false at the beginning of the `\tableofcontents`.

This prevents the generation of the same label again (unless `\newtest` is used again after resetting of the test counter!)

In the `ToC` stage, the already written label is extracted with `\getrefnumber` (requires `refcount` package). (A `\ref` usage would work too, but there would be a hyperlink then, if `hyperref` is used in addition).

Be sure to say `\notintoctrue` after `\tableofcontents`!

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen,bookmarksopenlevel=3]{hyperref}

\newcounter{test}

\makeatletter

\newif\ifnotintoc

\DeclareRobustCommand{\newtest}[1]{%
  \ifnotintoc
  \refstepcounter{test}\label{test:#1}% 
  Test \thetest\ #1%
  \else
  Test \getrefnumber{test:#1}\ #1%
  \fi
}

\g@addto@macro{\tableofcontents}{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\global\protect\notintocfalse}}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

   \title{Test example}

   \maketitle

   \clearpage

   \tableofcontents
   \notintoctrue
   \clearpage

   \section{Design tests}
   \subsection{\newtest{A test}}
   \subsection{\newtest{Another test}}
   \section{Functional tests}
   \subsection{\newtest{Yet another test}}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The only problem I've experienced with this solution is that the PDF bookmarks have a wrong text. Instead of "Test 1. A test", the bookmark is "testTest1. A test"

Comment: @Enrique: Not for me. I can post a screenshot of the bookmarks too.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved by resetting counter next to `Table of Contents`:

```
   \tableofcontents
   \setcounter{test}{0}
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem with multiply defined lables!

Comment: I agree this...